# strange behavior with comment position

Tags: comments, plugin-jetpack, theme-twenty-twelve

I've created a custom `content.php` and removed any comments on the `content.php` page

then i changed the `sharing-service.php` from jetpack and added `comments_popup_link` there:

```
// Wrapper
$sharing_content .= '<div class="sharedaddy sd-sharing-enabled">';
$sharing_content .= '<div class="robots-nocontent sd-block sd-social sd-social-' . $global['button_style'] . ' sd-sharing">';

if ( $global['sharing_label'] != '' )
    $sharing_content .= '<h3 class="sd-title">'. comments_popup_link(  __( 'Leave a reply', 'changed2012' ) , __( '1 Reply', 'changed2012' ), __( '% Replies', 'changed2012' ) ) . $global['sharing_label'] . '</h3>';
$sharing_content .= '<div class="sd-content"><ul>';
```

and it looks like this:
[image: comment position]
[image]

does anyone have an idea why its getting moved there? and how i can move it back where it should be?

Comment: `comments_popup_link()` *prints* the result, and can therefore not be used in a string concatenation. I am not aware of an equivalent function to *return* a similar output.

Comment: See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17763 ("comments_popup_link() need a get_* version")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably just buffer the output from comments_popup_link in a separate function.

```
function get_comments_popup_link( $zero = false, $one = false, $more = false, $css_class = '', $none = false ) {
    ob_start();
    comments_popup_link( $zero, $one, $more, $css_class, $none );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: you might want to prefix the function name to avoid trouble in the future, e.g. `wpse80387_get_comments_popup_link`

Comment: ah thats a good point, thx

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael points out, "`comments_popup_link()` prints the result, and can therefore not be used in a string concatenation" when returning output. There's a [patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17763) available, or you could use following workaround, something I wrote a while ago, adapted to your markup:

```
if ( $global['sharing_label'] != '' ) {
    global $post;
    $comments_link_txt = ( get_comments_number( $post->ID ) != 0 ) ? sprintf( _n( '1 Reply', '%1$s Replies', get_comments_number( $post->ID ), 'changed2012' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number( $post->ID ) ) ) : __( 'Leave a reply', 'changed2012' );
    $sharing_content .= '<h3 class="sd-title"><a href="' . get_comments_link( $post->ID ) . '">' . $comments_link_txt . '</a>' . $global['sharing_label'] . '</h3>';
}
```

Comment: when i apply the patch, does the next update remove the patch again?